# Datagridview Unicode Entry

Tags: vb.net, unicode, datagridview, keyboard

Im using datagridview for entry. Im using EditOnKeystroke edit mode. It works fine with non unicode mode. But in unicode mode keydown, keypress or the edit mode start are  not fired.

how to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what this question about at all, please add some tags and elaborate a bit.

Comment: Im using datagridview with the edit mode property is set to : EditOnKeystroke. While in no unicode keyboard it is fine (ie. whenever i type a key, the cell goes to editmode) But in unicode keyboard mode no other keys (except the spacebar and del keys) are detected. And im not able to goto edit mode unless with a mousclick on the cell.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about. Is this about programming? If so what programming language? What framework?

Comment: vb.net programming. The problem in simple is no keydown,keypress fired when using Unicode keyboard in datagridview.

Comment: I can't really find anything about a "unicode keyboard" online, what do you mean?

Comment: unicode keys (not keyboard) :)

Comment: unicode keys (not keyboard) :) My native language (Tamil) letters (அம்மா like)